# Failed to initiate one-to-many relationships (Call to a member function toArray() on a non-object)

Tags: symfony, doctrine, one-to-many

I'm to prepare a classical 1:n relation in order to list *szervezets* (~organizations) and *kapcsolats* (~contacts) below. These are the entities (relevant part only).

Szervezet:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Szervezet
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="szervezet")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Szervezet
{

...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Kapcsolat", mappedBy="szervezet")
     */
     private $kapcsolats;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->kapcsolats = new ArrayCollection();
    } 

    public function getKapcsolats() {
        return $this->kapcsolats->toArray();
    }
}
```

Kapcsolat:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Kapcsolat
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="kapcsolat")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Kapcsolat
{

...

    /**
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Szervezet
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Szervezet", inversedBy="kapcsolats")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="szervezet_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $szervezet;

    /**
     * Get szervezet
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Szervezet
     */
    public function getSzervezet()
    {
        return $this->szervezet;
    }
}
```

Now if I want to list them via this controller and template I get an error:

*Error: Call to a member function toArray() on a non-object*

Controller:

```
/**
 *
 * @Route("/show/{id}", name="szervezet_show")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template("admin/szervezet/show.html.twig")
 */
public function showAction($id) {
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()-> getRepository('AppBundle:Szervezet');
    $szervezet = $repository->findOneById($id);

...

    $kapcsolats = $szervezet->getKapcsolats();

    return array(
        'szervezet' => $szervezet,
        'kapcsolats' => $kapcsolats,
    );
}
```

Template:

```
{% for kapcsolat in kapcsolats %}   
    <div class="cimke w150">{{ kapcsolat.kapcsolatTipus }}</div>
    <div class="ertek">{{ kapcsolat.id }}</div>     
{% endfor %}
```

Database filled, I can list them with a normal query, but not via annotations. Any idea what I've missed?

Answer (score 0):

Szervezet Entity to like this (Note: delete toArray()):

```
    public function __construct() {
       $this->kapcsolats = new ArrayCollection();
    } 

    public function getKapcsolats() {
        return $this->kapcsolats;
    }
```

Kapcsolat Entitiy:

```
/**
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Szervezet
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Szervezet", inversedBy="kapcsolats")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="szervezet_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
*/
```

to

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Szervezet", inversedBy="kapcsolats")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="szervezet_id", referencedColumnName="id")
*/
private $szervezet;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is just a tiny bit better but still not perfect. Deleting toArray() results an empty list - but no error, at least. However, there are two entries in the DB. The rest had no effect, as far as I see.

Comment: Can you see FK relations in you database ? If you can't, you need update your schema.

Comment: Closer. :) In fact, the solution was to delete xml definitions that I used for reverse engineering and than configure doctrine to look for annotations instead. So, practically, no matter what I did before with annotations it had no effect. Thanks for your time!